# Django: Can I map the output of a template variable to another string?

Tags: django, django-templates

I am working with Django's generic views, specifically `django.views.generic.date_based.archive_month`.

This views sets the template context to include `date_list` which contains a list of the relevant python `datetime.datetime` objects. (See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-date-based-archive-month)

This my simple template to use this view:

```
<html>
        <head>
                <title>Entries index</title>
        </head>
        <body>
                <h1>Entries index by month: {{ month|date:"F" }}</h1>
                <h2>Day:</h2>
                {% for datetime_object in date_list %}
                        <ul><a href="/weblog/{{ year }}/{{ month.month }}/{{ datetime_object.day }}/">{{ datetime_object.day }}</a></ul>
                {% endfor %}
        </body>
</html>
```

My problem is that although I can get the numerical month, say 3 for march, my urls are set up to use the three letter representation, i.e. `mar` for march, so that `<a href=` block isn't pointing to the right url.

How can I set up a mapping to map each of the month's numerical value to their three letter representation?

Comment: Apologies if I'm missing something. Can you use the built-in `date` template tag with the `b` format character?  E.g. `.../{{ month|date:"b" }}/...`

Comment: Bingo. If you make this a response I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: Although, I still do wonder if it's possible to do some sort of mapping with template variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [the built-in `date` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#date) with the `b` format character.
Applied example below:

```
<ul>
  <!-- whitespace added below solely for readability 
       I do not recommend adding such whitespace in your code -->
  <a href="/weblog/{{ year }}/{{ month|date:"b" }}/{{ datetime_object.day }}/">
    {{ datetime_object.day }}
  </a>
</ul>
```